# Laravel place validation stuff

Tags: validation, laravel

Laravel version - 5.0.0

Laravel offers so many ways to validate so I cannot choose what to use. Because no one of them suits my tastes.

What I want: full management of validation process. I want a class which:

- has got `rules` property, but it I can modify them any time
- can return break validation process if any rule fails; add rules to validator
- has got custom messages
- communicate with other classes which have got `validate` method as well as their own messages.
- manage redirects and return values

Basically I do not want to extend validation class but simple use it. I think, form requests could do what I want. But now I do not understand their purpose. They are very poor in Laravel. Also, I do not want place all this in controller.

So, the only way is to create a custom class?

Comment: yep - if you don't like it, make your own.

Comment: ..but it really sounds like you are asking too much of a validation class. Think 'Single Responsibility Principle' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle. A controller should manage redirects, not a validation class.

Comment: @Gaz_Edge I know. But I already think for two days how to design it and cannot make a desicion. I thought about extending validation class, but on the other hand do not understand why. The point is that I have got a lot of conditions and some connected classes. If I start decoupling this I will have much more code.

Comment: yes - welcome to the world of compromise :-) If you don't want to spend the time developing it, clearly its not that important to you